# Calculated Column DataGridView - C#

Tags: c#, datagridview, calculated-columns

I am trying to get a calculated column in DataGridView, at first I thought it was simple but now I have been struggling for an hour.
The code below works fine when editing columns:

```
private void ReceiptDataGrid_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{            
    DataGridViewRow RecieptRow = RecieptDataGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    RecieptRow.Cells[4].Value = double.Parse(RecieptRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString()) * double.Parse(RecieptRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString());            
}
```

But I am struggling to make the column take its value automatically when new rows are added.
I get a NullReferenceException
exception when I use the same code.
I have tried a for loop and got the same error

```
private void RecieptDataGrid_RowsAdded(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < e.RowCount; i++)
  {
       DataGridViewRow RecieptRow = RecieptDataGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex + i];
      RecieptRow.Cells[4].Value = double.Parse(RecieptRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString()) * double.Parse(RecieptRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString());         
  }                       
}
```

I Realize that it sees the cells at nulls about is there a workaround to this?
Help please.

Thank You.

Comment: when a new row is added, there is a high chance that all the cells values are null so how could you calculate some value from those nulls?

Comment: For future reference the name of the exception you're receiving is a `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: I am new to C#, I understand the problem but is there a workaround to this?

Comment: @ArmendImeri it depends on when an how you add a new row? if you prepare some values for some cells and just leave a cell empty (for later calculation), your handler for RowsAdded may work, but I think your situation may be different, normally we should update a cell only when other cells' values change, that's the point which is always true.

Answer (score 0):

you could check if your RecieotRow is a new row (with empty values) by using the IsNewRow property:

```
for (int i = 0; i < e.RowCount; i++)
{
   DataGridViewRow RecieptRow = RecieptDataGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex + i];

   if (RecieptRow.IsNewRow) continue;

   RecieptRow.Cells[4].Value = double.Parse(RecieptRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString()) * double.Parse(RecieptRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString());         
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, it was reading the row default values as nulls.
I replaced the default properties by adding the default value to the string that adds data to the DataGrid.